# Software Center stops

Tags: software-center, synaptic

When I wanna see the list of installed applications or search for a new one, the panels changes to blank white and stops there with waiting mouse cursor! And Synaptic give an error on one of the repositories and leaves (Nautilus elementary) the relevant source file has only one word in it 'ain' which is mentioned in the error by Synaptic. Should I delete or change it into comment in the file ? If so how?

Answer (score 1):

Do you use PPAs? Try to deactivate them in *Software Sources* > *Other Software* tab, and do `sudo apt-get update` in a terminal.